# When I use the virustotal API, I used requests.get and got an error [Errno 11004] getaddrinfo failed

Tags: python

My code:

```
import requests
url = 'https://www.virustotal.com/vtapi/v2/file/behaviour'
params = {'apikey':'--private API--','hash':'0240ed7e45567f606793dafaff024acf'}
response = requests.get(url, params=params)
print response.json()
```

I got error:
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError:

> HTTPSConnectionPool(host='vtcuckoo.commondatastorage.googleapis.com',
>   port=443): Max retries exceeded with url:
>   /14461260f9b3988d4eb4e46bc7d9861172266a9a01bf15c57916a9e4f9dc0618?GoogleAccessId=758681729565-rc7fgq07icj8c9dm2gi34a4cckv235v1@developer.gserviceaccount.com&Expires=1529402918&Signature=P5JSJJvot6%2B1%2FIHCOs9RZWSofnTxiEDwRRhUwoM5YnDnLFf8Rq9LGEu5nPMegBQ1D9r8pZCluy2k%0AbdK70w%2BiRCLgXtplNTnKFEqSRu9oyI7jUXLeeObMbEht7mlxjkiKkrNzbtLm9lE6kL7UUcRYYuXp%0AKwhoN9jJez3aTvnJBEU%3D
>   (Caused by
>   NewConnectionError(': Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 11004]
>   getaddrinfo failed',))

why?

Answer (score 0):

Hi try changing the URL to file/report.

```
 params = {'apikey': '', 'resource':hash}
 headers = {"Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate","User-Agent" : "gzip,  My Python requests library example client or username"}
 response_dict = requests.get('https://www.virustotal.com/vtapi/v2/file/report', params=params).json()
```

For reference check this repo [Virustotal_apiclient](https://github.com/ajaykumarkk/virustotal_apiclient)

Answer (score 0):

You need to insert the private API in the params.
in order to get a private API, you need to sign up to https://virustotal.com